# как выйти из хэндлера telebot до следующего вызова

Tags: python, telebot, handlers

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста как "выключить" хандлер до следующего вызова команды. В коде бота в телеграмм написал игру в камень ножницы бумага но не могу понять как выйти из игры что бы можно было спокойно использовать другие функции. Вот код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['game']) # игра в камень ножницы бумага
def game(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    markup.add(types.KeyboardButton(''), types.KeyboardButton('✂️'), types.KeyboardButton(''), types.KeyboardButton('❌'))
    bot.reply_to(message, "Добро пожаловать в игру 'Камень, ножницы, бумага'! Для игры используйте кнопки ниже:", reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, callback=play_game)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def play_game(message):
    user_choice = message.text
    bot_choice = random.choice(['', '✂️', '', '❌'])
    if user_choice not in ['', '✂️', '', '❌']:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Пожалуйста, используйте кнопки для выбора камня, ножниц или бумаги.")
        return

    if user_choice == bot_choice:
        bot.reply_to(message, f"Вы выбрали {user_choice}, а я выбрал {bot_choice}. Ничья!")
    elif (user_choice == '' and bot_choice == '✂️') or (user_choice == '✂️' and bot_choice == '') or (user_choice == '' and bot_choice == ''):
        bot.reply_to(message, f"Вы выбрали {user_choice}, а я выбрал {bot_choice}. Вы победили! ")
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message, f"Вы выбрали {user_choice}, а я выбрал {bot_choice}. Я победил! ")
    if message.text == '❌':
        a = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
        msg=bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Игра окончена! Возвращайся ещё', reply_markup=a)
```

Если сменить

```
func=lambda message: True
```

На

```
func=lambda commands: commands == 'game'
```

То хандлер с игрой запускается лишь на один раз. Как обойти захват сообщений этим хандлером и нормально играть до прерывания игры командой

```
if message.text == '❌':
```

В кодах я хуже чем ноль а бота пишу чисто для себя. Не бейте тапками

Answer (score 0):

Идея в чем, пока не нажмем ❌, мы будем перерегистрировать следующий обработчик на нашу же функцию с игрой `bot.register_next_step_handler(message, callback=play_game)`.

После того как нажимаем ❌, мы снимаем `bot.clear_step_handler_by_chat_id(message.chat.id)` регистрацию следующего шага с игры и получаем доступ к основному обработчику сообщений.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import random

TOKEN = 'Token'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['game']) # игра в камень ножницы бумага
def game(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    markup.add(types.KeyboardButton(''), types.KeyboardButton('✂️'), types.KeyboardButton(''), types.KeyboardButton('❌'))
    bot.reply_to(message, "Добро пожаловать в игру 'Камень, ножницы, бумага'! Для игры используйте кнопки ниже:", reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, callback=play_game)
    
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_messages(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Привет, я приглашаю тебя сыгрыть в игру /game")        

def play_game(message):
    user_choice = message.text
    bot_choice = random.choice(['', '✂️', ''])
    if user_choice not in ['', '✂️', '', '❌']:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Пожалуйста, используйте кнопки для выбора камня, ножниц или бумаги.")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, callback=play_game)

    if user_choice == bot_choice:
        bot.reply_to(message, f"Вы выбрали {user_choice}, и я выбрал {bot_choice}. Ничья!")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, callback=play_game)
    elif (user_choice == '' and bot_choice == '✂️') or (user_choice == '✂️' and bot_choice == '') or (user_choice == '' and bot_choice == ''):
        bot.reply_to(message, f"Вы выбрали {user_choice}, а я выбрал {bot_choice}. Вы победили! ")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, callback=play_game)
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message, f"Вы выбрали {user_choice}, а я выбрал {bot_choice}. Я победил! ")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, callback=play_game)
    if message.text == '❌':  
        a = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
        msg=bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Игра окончена! Возвращайся ещё', reply_markup=a)
        bot.clear_step_handler_by_chat_id(message.chat.id)
        
bot.polling()
```